# Incorrect placement of "the"?

Tags: word-order, word-position

Does this sentence make sense? 
"I can't sympathise with the many people who are impatient."
Should "the" be dropped from the sentence? I couldn't find a similar answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't sympathise with the many people who are impatient.

This says that there are many impatient people (in the world or where you work for example) and you can't sympathise with them. In fact you can't sympathise with any of them - not even one.

> I can't sympathise with many people who are impatient.

This means that you *can* sympathise with some impatient people but only a few (i.e. not many).

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the article, your sentence says that you can't sympathize with a numerous subset of those people who are impatient, but you imply that that there are still some impatient people outside that subset with whom you can sympathize.

If you keep the article, you have identified a particular set of people, namely the impatient, and you note that you have no sympathy for any of them.

Comment: Frankie - deadrat and I answered at the same time and our answers agree. We say the same thing in different words.